# How to convert escaped http request data to a normal string

Tags: .net, json, string, escaping, decode

I am using .net 3.5 to write  a simple REST web service. This will use JSON to pass data to and from it. I have a simple test HTML page I am using to send POST data to the service. When I receive the data it is all encoded. Fair enough, so I should be able to simply decode it. This is where I am having the problem. I have searched Stackoverflow but can't find find any solutions.

Here is the test HTML I am using to generate the test. I think it is is correct.

```
<input type="text/json" id="contact" name="contact" value='{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Organisation":"","AddressID":null,"Status":0,"Credits":1,"Type":1,"ExpiryDate":null,"UserName":"","Password":"","CustomerIconURL":"","CountryCode":"UK","LastUpdated":null,"DateCreated":"2013-03-29T17:25:41.667"}' readonly="readonly" />
<input type="submit" value="send POST" />
```

I am receiving the data from the request with the following code snippet..

```
Stream stream = context.Request.InputStream;
byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
string JsonBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

..this returns me the following string

```
@"contact=%7B%22FirstName%22%3A%22John%22%2C%22LastName%22%3A%22Doe%22%2C%22Organisation%22%3A%22%22%2C%22AddressID%22%3Anull%2C%22Status%22%3A0%2C%22Credits%22%3A1%2C%22Type%22%3A1%2C%22ExpiryDate%22%3Anull%2C%22UserName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Password%22%3A%22%22%2C%22CustomerIconURL%22%3A%22%22%2C%22CountryCode%22%3A%22UK%22%2C%22LastUpdated%22%3Anull%2C%22DateCreated%22%3A%222013-03-29T17%3A25%3A41.667%22%7D";
```

.. so I thought it would be relatively each to decode (un-encode?) this string but cannot quite get it ... The nearest I have managed is by using the following..

```
string JsonBody = Uri.UnescapeDataString(JsonBody);
```

but this returns me the following ...

```
"@contact={\"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"Doe\",\"Organisation\":\"\",\"AddressID\":null,\"Status\":0,\"Credits\":1,\"Type\":1,\"ExpiryDate\":null,\"UserName\":\"\",\"Password\":\"\",\"CustomerIconURL\":\"\",\"CountryCode\":\"UK\",\"LastUpdated\":null,\"DateCreated\":\"2013-03-29T17:25:41.667\"}"
```

and I cannot find a way of remove the `\"`to `"` . I realise this signifies that the `"`are still escaped but even with using

```
JsonBody = JsonBody.Replace(@"\", "");
```

..which I though should work, didn't.

So if anyone has a neat way of solving this I'd appreciate it. Perhaps I am sending the string in an incorrect form from the HTML? The clients of the web service will written using various platforms, Drupal for one. So I thought i'd use a simple HTML test page to start with to generate the test uri ..

Many thanks for any thoughts you may have.

Richard H

Comment: Your string does  not contain `\"`s. You see it that way in debugger. (use the magnifier icon and see the actual string)

Comment: Wow. So simple. Thank you 14V for replying so quickly. Very embarrassed. A question though, why has the debugger put the `\"`in ?, if it has removed them from the string, why keep them in the display?